# Calling WSDL web service from inside CRM using Javascript

Tags: javascript, web-services, dynamics-crm-2011

I should invoke a WSDL web service from a CRM form.
I haven't found any possible solution that was able to overcome the cross domain issue.
Is there a fix for that?

Using PHP is not an option.
The alternative would be to use a custom entity and create a new record at every request. Then to fire a plugin on create of the entity and thus having some C# code that takes care of the dirty work.

Which is the best option?

Comment: Yes, it is on premise

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you seen following articles?
http://mscrmshop.blogspot.com/2012/07/crm2011-and-cross-domain-calls-part-1.html

http://mscrmshop.blogspot.com/2012/07/crm2011-and-cross-domain-calls-part-2.html

Your suggestion is a good workaround actually that was actively used.

Comment: It's best to include the relevant parts of linked pages in case links go dead.